# MySQL returning different values for CRC32() with same string

Tags: mysql, sql, crc32, sql-insert

I am having a bizarre issue with two queries returning different hash values for CRC32 with the same string.

If I run:

`SELECT 'http://mywebsite4.com/myvideos', CRC32('http://mywebsite4.com/myvideos');`

The hash values returned are 3769016377.

If I then run

`INSERT INTO locations (full_url, full_url_hash) VALUES ('http://mywebsite4.com/myvideos', CRC32('http://mywebsite4.com/myvideos'))`

The hash values inserted are 2147483647.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing here? As far as I understand the CRC32 function should always hash equal strings to equal 32 bit integers, I can't for the life of me figure out why they're different in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your datatype of the column into `INT UNSIGNED`. The reason for that is you are using `SIGNED INT` that's why the maximum value is only `2147483647`.

```
CREATE TABLE tableNAME
(
    full_url_hash INT UNSIGNED
    -- other columns
)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f552b/1)